# Open Outlook (aaplication or browser) and populate recipient field

Tags: javascript, email, outlook, articulate-storyline

I'm a learning designer working in Articulate Storyline. I've asked this on their community site but its been suggested to ask here. In Articulate I have the option to add in Javascript under what they call triggers, this is the query I have.

When the button is clicked, I would like specifically Outlook to open and the recipient field to be populated with a certain email address. From what I have searched so far, I understand I can open Outlook's browser version using `window.open("https://outlook.live.com/mail/0/")`. When added to the trigger this works. However, I can't see where the `mailto` command would sit with this.

Is it even possible to open the compose mail window in a browser and or is there anyway to open the desktop application instead.

Thanks for any advice or help you can give me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it even possible to open the compose mail window in a browser and or is there anyway to open the desktop application instead.

Use the [mailto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa767737(v=vs.85)) protocol which opens a client's e-mail system and begins a new email message. For example:

```
<a href="mailto:user@example.com?
    subject=MessageTitle&amp;
    body=Message Content">
    Contact Us</a>
```

The following example shows how to use an HTML form to create an e-mail message.

```
<form action="mailto:user@example.com" method="get">
<input name="subject" type="hidden" value="Message Title">

Feedback:<br/>
<textarea name=body cols="40">
Please share your thoughts here
and then choose Send Feedback.
</textarea>

<input type="submit" value="Send Feedback">
</form>
```

For more information on the `mailto` protocol, see [RFC2368: The mailto URL scheme](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=203480).

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks for your help. The client needs it to specifically open Outlook as the email must come from the users educational account not personal. I can get the browser version of outlook to open but not on the compose email window or with the recipient field filled in. Is this possible via outlook desktop or browser? Thanks again.

Comment: Web browsers don't deal with COM servers, only Internet Explorer (not Edge) can run run JavaScript where you could automate Outlook.

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing the specifics of Articulate Storyline, but if you can add HTML one option is to use a regular "a" tag for this. It will open in the e-mail client that is default on the users computer though, which may be Outlook or something else.

```
<a href="mailto:jane.doe@somewhere.com">Email link</a>
```

You can read more here:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_address.asp

Comment: Thanks Culme for your help. I tried that but it turns out it doesn't allow html to be added to triggers only Javascript. Html animations are allowed and that's where the confusion was. Thanks for the link, do you by any chance know of a good resource for javascript?

Comment: Yeah, the `mailto` protocol doesn't support HTML based message bodies.